# How to determine color temperature by computer?

Tags: color-theory

Hello I need to figure out if skin tones (real ones from photographies) are either warm or cool. As I'm having difficulties assessing with my eyes only I wondered if there was a tool that would tell me if there is more yellow or blue in the image.
I don't know if it would be a reliable technique, and if it's cyan or magenta that gives the coolness.

Comment: Temperature as defined by physicist or a art teacher? Anyway Lab color mode should give you the absolute axes you want.

Comment: Ok you really need to calrify your question. What is the end usecase i mean if you plan on taking radom pictures online and estimate form there it makes no sense. If your trying to match to physical objects then its a really really hard problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't measure **real** skin tones from a random photograph alone. It's not possible, because there are too many unknowns.

You'd need to know the precise lighting at the time of shooting, how it interacts with the subject, the white balance applied in the camera could be off, what the precise exposure settings were, etc, etc.

However, if you are the photographer, it is possible using a calibration card such as a SpyderCheckr during shooting to create a custom calibration profile to ensure the colours in the photograph match reality as close as possible. Watch [this video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5UTTNF_yXf4) which should kinda give you an idea of what is involved. This process is really only suitable in a studio situation where lighting and exposure can be controlled precisely.

I'm not going to go into more detail here. If you want more info, might be better to ask about this in Photography Stack Exchange.

Comment: There is some additional info about why the OP wants to measure skin tones in the comments to Tetsujin's answer.

Comment: @Wolf - Yeah, I read them. Tthe OP is trying to match real world clothing colours with real world skin tones in a photo which may or may not match reality. To match reality, you'd need to calibrate the photo in some way. In addition you'd also probably need to use a hardware calibration device to calibrate the monitor.

Comment: By "match" I *think* the OP means "find colors fitting for a certain skin tone". Not "make color of clothes the same as skin color". It's a fashion thing. Like [this](https://www.thelist.com/20621/best-clothing-colors-skin-tone/). I might be wrong here.

Comment: @Wolff Yeah, I get that. But even so, you can't tell if colours are too warm or too cool for someone's complexion if you don't know what their skin tone actually looks like. If a photo is not shot properly under controlled lighting, all bets are off.   Having the wrong white balance alone would make this task virtually impossible.

Comment: Sorry to nitpick, but so many words are said already so I might as well nitpick all the way through.  The OP mentions that "we'll assume here that the image do match the original temperature". (Really the question should be clarified)

Comment: @Wolff LOL, and to that I could reply "when you  assume things, you make an ASS out of U and ME" ;)

Comment: @BillyKerr I asked how to measure temperature and you tell me about calibration and spaces... You are making it over complicated. How do graphic designers know if a color is warm or cool ? Don't they need to know this at some point ?

Comment: @WaterBearer they dont measure it, they would base it on feeling. Anwyay, the graphic designer has exactly the same problem unless they have a caibrated space they dont really know if the color is warm or cool once the picture is printed. Asking thuis kind of question on web images is nonsensical as you dont know what the end user monitor shows.

Comment: @Waterbearer  - No, the problem here is this is not as simple as you think. It's not trivial. Yes it is complicated. Graphic designers calibrate their monitors and devices to get precise colour control, and also use standardised colour swatch books.

Comment: @BillyKerr do you know yes or no how to measure with a tool if a color is warm or cool ?

Comment: It's easy if you have a known-good calibrated workflow, as we've been trying to tell you. You also need accurate definitions of 'warm' & 'cool' for your specific need. No living human is ever going to have *actually* cool-toned skin, so this is a 'fashion' definition, not a 'real' one.

Answer (score 1):

If a skin tone is cyan-ish is way off. I understand that you are using a CMYK color mode. But pay more attention to yellow and magenta. But try to correct skin tone in RGB mode.

The skin tone is basically orange with different levels of saturation and lightness, so it becomes brown or beige.

It can be yellower or redder.

The tool used to measure this is a vectorscope. One problem is that there are no vectorscope integrated in any photo retouching application I know, only on video color grading ones.

You can download and use Davinci Resolve for free. https://www.blackmagicdesign.com/mx/products/davinciresolve/

It has a vectorscope and they have a specific line, the skin tone line. You select a section of the skin you want to measure and the graph should be next to this line.

https://www.google.com/search?q=vectorscope+davinci+resolve+skin+tone

Answer (score 0):

To know for sure you need a hardware colorimeter to correctly calibrate & profile your display.

After that, it's just a case of hovering your cursor over the image with an on-screen colour meter to see which shows 'most' or in the case of this very dodgy composited image I found on the interweb, how much overpowering yellow (too much green;)

[image]

For skin tones, at a rough guess, red needs to be stronger than blue by 30 - 50% otherwise it will start to look quite cool.

One distinct advantage of using the colour meter is that you can move it well away from any other distractions, so you're just seeing that portion of colour with no other background to influence what you see.
An example of that is visible in my screen-shot, where I didn't move the meter away - because the background is pink, it makes you feel the grey of the meter is slightly blue-ish. if you hover a meter over that image, you'll see it's a perfect neutral grey.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/124460/discussion-on-answer-by-tetsujin-how-to-determine-color-temperature-by-computer).